Findthrust.cmake (math) math cannot parse the expression
I'm trying to build Open3D on ubuntu 24.04, CUDA v: V12.5.40, cmake version 3.28.3, gcc (Ubuntu 13.2.0-23ubuntu4) 13.2.0 with following command:
cmake  \
  -D GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=OFF \
  -D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON  \
  -D BUILD_CUDA_MODULE=ON  \      
  -D BUILD_PYTORCH_OPS=OFF \
  -D BUILD_TENSORFLOW_OPS=OFF \
  -D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=$(which python) \
  -D BUILD_PYTHON_MODULE=ON \
  -D BUILD_GUI=ON \
  -D USE_SYSTEM_TBB=ON ..

But when I run make -j10 I get:
CMake Error at cmake/Findthrust.cmake:17 (math):
  math cannot parse the expression: "200400 // macro expansion with ##
  requires this to be a single value / 100000": syntax error, unexpected
  exp_DIVIDE (9).
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  src/stdgpu/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


CMake Error at cmake/Findthrust.cmake:18 (math):
  math cannot parse the expression: "(200400 // macro expansion with ##
  requires this to be a single value / 100) % 1000": syntax error, unexpected
  exp_DIVIDE (10).
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  src/stdgpu/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


CMake Error at cmake/Findthrust.cmake:19 (math):
  math cannot parse the expression: "200400 // macro expansion with ##
  requires this to be a single value % 100": syntax error, unexpected
  exp_DIVIDE (9).
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  src/stdgpu/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.28/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find thrust: Found unsuitable version "ERROR.ERROR.ERROR", but
  required is at least "1.9.2" (found
  /usr/local/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.28/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:598 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  cmake/Findthrust.cmake:26 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  src/stdgpu/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)

Can you please tell me how can I solve that please? thanks.
P.S: related issue

https://github.com/NVIDIA/thrust/blob/main/thrust/cmake/README.md#fixing-legacy-findthrustcmake
